# Class method with the same name of the class

Tags: python, oop

I am new to Python and was amazed to see that there are class method which has the same name of the class.

I already tried to check on some online documentation, but there aren't any references on how is this used. What is the idea behind this implementation?

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.doSomething()

    def myClass(self):
        self.doSomething2()
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Since the names of the class and function are at different levels, they do not collide. Thus, they are just ordinary class and function names, and you can do `mc = myClass()` to instantiate the class followed by `mc.myClass()` to call the function. Why this is done, though, is beyond me. It seems like bad practice, but maybe there are valid use cases.

Comment: Also it doesn't conform to PEP8 so is possibly written by someone more familiar with another language. The class would be `MyClass()` and the method `my_class()`. But that's again speculation.

Comment: It is similar to having functions with the same name as their enclosing module.  For example `from pprint import pprint` where the `pprint` function is in the `pprint` module.  No conflict.  It's a namespace thing.  But remember, in my example, the reference `pprint` after the import will refer to the function, not the module.